# TextWatcher - Difference between s and et.getText().toString()

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am attaching a textwatcher to an edittext. Following this site http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html I have a very small question. What's the difference between s and edittext.getText().toString()? Don't they both refer to the text that is currently written on the edditext? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes, but a `CharSequence` differs from a `String` in that they may have Spans attached (fonts, colors, &c).

It's exactly the same instance as what `getText()` returns, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
CharSequence s
```

is actually `edittext.getText()` every Time you entered a character from the edittext `s` changes and so as the `edittext.getText()`. what `.toString()` is doing is that it is converting the `CharSequence` to `String`.

In conclusion `s == edittext.getText()`.

Answer (score 1):

In use is the same thing, but in performance is better using s, because

s = EditText.getText()

So, if you use EditText.getText().toString(), you are executing the same function twice.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between `s` and `edittext.getText().toString()`?

I assume you mean the `s` as in the parameter from `onTextChanged` and `beforeTextChanged`.

> Don't they both refer to the text that is currently written on the edditext?

Basically yes, that is right.

Since Android is open source we can see it in the source. The [`getText()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L1471-L1473) method:

```
public CharSequence getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

And we can see [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3769) in the `setText()` method:

```
mText = text;
```

followed by [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3816):

```
sendOnTextChanged(text, 0, oldlen, textLength);
```

As you can see the `text` passed in as an argument to `sendOnTextChanged` (a method that notifies every attached `TextWatcher` of the changes in the `EditText`) is the same as the instance variable `mText` returned in `getText()`.

So `EditText#getText()` and the s parameter in the `onTextChanged` and `beforeTextChanged` are the same. However they return a `CharSequence`. Once you call `toString()` on it you convert it to a `String`.